# How to generate C# documentation to a CHM or HTML file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xml-documentation

Is there a way to generate a readable document file from the documentation on the code directly from Visual Studio? (also considering 2010)

Code example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert a number to string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number">An integer number to be converted to string</param>
/// <returns>Number as string</returns>
/// <example>
/// <code>
///     var s = MyMethod(5);
/// </code>
/// </example>
/// <exception cref="Exception">In case it can't convert</exception>
/// <remarks>
/// Whatever
/// </remarks>
public string MyMethod(int number)
{
    return number.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) can do it directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: Great tool! Already works with Visual Studio 2010, very simple to use and generate great documentations.

Answer (score 9):

Use [DocProject](http://docproject.codeplex.com/). It can create HTML docs as well CHM. You should install [Sandcastle](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle) first.

Comment: It is not working on my Windows 7 x64. DocProject just crash all the time

Comment: Sandcastle work perfect with me, I used the "SandcastleGui.exe" tool, Thanks!.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

Comment: +1 for doxygen after fighting with sandcastle.  IMO Easier to use and nicer looking results

Answer (score 2):

[Sandcastle Help File builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) is another one

Comment: This is the best. Has support for VS2010, VS2012, VS2013 and probably also VS2014 at the end of the year. You can export to MS Word, HTML, CHM and other Help formats.