# how to generate c# documentation to a chm or html file in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, documentation-generation

i have read [How to generate C# documentation to a CHM or HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838788/how-to-generate-c-sharp-documentation-to-a-chm-or-html-file). but, i use visual studio 2012 and all of the answer to that question is in visual studio 2010 and lower. so, how i generate it in visual studio 2012?

Comment: Did you try to follow the advice at all? Or did you assume it was completely different and not try at all?

Comment: now i'm downloading sandcastle(link from @hutchonoid)

Comment: It is also mentioned in an answer to the question you linked to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sandcastle Help File Builder is my favourite..

http://shfb.codeplex.com/

You simply code as normal and it generates itself.

There is a getting started tutorial here:

http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/Index.aspx?topic=html/b772e00e-1705-4062-adb6-774826ce6700.htm

Answer (score 3):

Sandcastle will certainly do the job, however I prefer [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) and it provides good documentation.  It can also generate class diagrams for your code.